# Layout containers in objective-c - do they exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, components

It begins my third month with XCode, iOS, objective-c and mac as well, I can tell that so far I'm disappointed to be as kind as I can be with my opinion. Maybe because I was spoiled by things that I had in hand when developing for other platforms like Android?

In any programming tasks where visuals are presented layout functionality is a MUST from the beginning, and like I could get functionality for layout in FLEX, JAVA or JAVA for Android (also have seen it working for Metro, XNA for Windows phones) but in iOS everything seems to be up-hill.

After this long introduction my question is quite simple, did someone tried to overcome this issue, namely are there any layout container components that can be brought to the Xcode project and use it e.g. linear layout?

Comment: What about layout constraints?

Comment: To echo @rmaddy's comment, I believe that anything you can do with android layout containers can be done with autolayout and layout constraints (and probably more if you really dig into them).

Comment: "probably more" well probably I've tried and failed so you can point to the "hidden" treasures of xcode interface builder gems:)

Comment: also I ask about objective-c code that will help with layout issues NOT to recommend another tool or any ones favourites.

Comment: And of course constraints are available for auto layout isn't it?

Comment: FWIW I didn't think this was a particularly bad question - I see lots worse

Answer (score 1):

People have written some Layout managers - you will find some here - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=layout but I agree with the commenters above, properly setting up layout constraints, although a little more time consuming at first, gives quite predictable and stable layout and you get quicker once you get familiar with them.

Comment: thanks I'll give a go with the cocoacontrols, I dont agree with commentators:) it is unnecessary hard in xcode comparing to other mobile platforms.